# Do not share vim navigation stack when opening new buffer

Tags: vim

If I navigate to a vim tag via `Ctrl-]` and then open a new buffer e.g. via `:new` the vim tag stack of the new buffer is shared with the old one (i.e. `:tags` will show the stack of the old buffer and also `Ctrl-T` in the new buffer will return to the tags of the old buffer). Is there a way to change this behavior so that the new buffer has a clear (empty) tag history? Is there an option to clear tag history on opening a new buffer by default?

Comment: What does "possible" mean to you? If you mean "is there an option I can set to have that behavior?", then the answer is *no*. If you mean "is it possible to write a script that does what I want?", then the answer is *maybe, what did you try?*.  FWIW, the tagstack is window-local, not buffer-local. See `:help tagstack`.